# Since Snapshot Isolation prevents dirty writes by using locks, aren't the writes already serialized?

Tags: database, transactions, distributed-transactions, transaction-isolation, snapshot-isolation

Snapshot Isolation (SI) doesn't allow dirty writes by using locks.  So where does Serializable Snapshot Isolation (SSI) come into picture?  Since locks are being used to prevent dirty writes in Snapshot Isolation, wouldn't the writes effectively be automatically *serialized*?